# Error while loading rust contract while creating sawtooth network

Tags: rust, hyperledger-sawtooth

I was trying to load the hyperledger grid smart contract to sawtooth network

after successfully running the docker-compose file with 4 active validator, i am getting following error

I have just logs one contract details rest 5 is giving me same error
I have also created a issue on sawtooth git repo click [HERE](https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-core/issues/2437)

```
➜  ~ docker logs tnt-contract-builder
Response Body:
Link { link: "http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008/batch_statuses?id=958c6a9e7577f16c812a66fbdf0d860b74c36237808cfaabc7910548fb5c8c81451d6ad41a59a50d14af9a81b7569511443dd4dab6067a262a43a3517f52b270" }
Response Body:
StatusResponse {"data":[{"id": "958c6a9e7577f16c812a66fbdf0d860b74c36237808cfaabc7910548fb5c8c81451d6ad41a59a50d14af9a81b7569511443dd4dab6067a262a43a3517f52b270", "status": "PENDING", "invalid_transactions": []}], "link": "http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008/batch_statuses?id=958c6a9e7577f16c812a66fbdf0d860b74c36237808cfaabc7910548fb5c8c81451d6ad41a59a50d14af9a81b7569511443dd4dab6067a262a43a3517f52b270&wait=30"}
Response Body:
Link { link: "http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008/batch_statuses?id=dc410ca4b86c35a7ce37f5b82a0c3c7a8209b980ad4638e6120b47703ba0fe9f6b02f717b68c89fb640b6cfda0d3f2e81f80f8750163d417e61141c09fa5bd53" }
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 11, kind: WouldBlock, message: "Resource temporarily unavailable" }', src/libcore/result.rs:1188:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
Response Body:
Link { link: "http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008/batch_statuses?id=eb421c54bb740a278fbd65ef37879a2fa193b897828cac1f250c8b8060899ce516b19c13fa63b1f081222402f2563dba7d707aace5c33594f587e7c8d5a051d9" }
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 11, kind: WouldBlock, message: "Resource temporarily unavailable" }', src/libcore/result.rs:1188:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
Response Body:
Link { link: "http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008/batch_statuses?id=a6d84ff7056902908026264bc224c046290f99337770d2b6913a5f76fe8ed5814e5277dc5244b9564d4d12823dc56a2ae1f7c4986f6ac7344a19a20fc382e639" }
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 11, kind: WouldBlock, message: "Resource temporarily unavailable" }', src/libcore/result.rs:1188:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
Response Body:
Link { link: "http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008/batch_statuses?id=a33bd2e40a34aac8399a8c39bfe073129a8abcaf23575247a521106af8eba43104aff6743efe26300a8ff3854dac20ec74492722d1f321aa02cf320131e83ef2" }
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 11, kind: WouldBlock, message: "Resource temporarily unavailable" }', src/libcore/result.rs:1188:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
Response Body:
Link { link: "http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008/batch_statuses?id=9e6140c04c1bd0cf39e281754bf4f8508fc07ab40887250f75e2dd13f9eab3cd4bf7ccacb8d3de88e0f52258627adc709dceaa501d80a18268b9fac8c869fcfb" }
```

this is my docker-compose file for creating sawtooth network and to load grid smart contract

```
version: "3.6"

volumes:
  contracts-shared:
  grid-shared:
  pbft-shared:
  gridd-alpha:
  templates-shared:
  cache-shared:

services:
  # ---== shared services ==---

  sabre-cli:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-sabre-cli:latest
    volumes:
      - contracts-shared:/usr/share/scar
      - pbft-shared:/pbft-shared
    container_name: sabre-cli
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  tnt-contract-builder:
    image: piashtanjin/tnt-contract-builder:latest
    container_name: tnt-contract-builder
    volumes:
      - pbft-shared:/pbft-shared
    entrypoint: |
      bash -c "
        while true; do curl -s http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008/state | grep -q head; if [ $$? -eq 0 ]; then break; fi; sleep 0.5; done;
        sabre cr --create grid_track_and_trace --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --owner $$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.pub) --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        sabre upload --filename /tmp/track_and_trace.yaml --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        sabre ns --create a43b46  --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --owner $$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.pub) --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        sabre perm a43b46 grid_track_and_trace --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --read --write --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        sabre perm 621dee01 grid_track_and_trace --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --read --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        sabre perm 621dee05 grid_track_and_trace --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --read --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        echo '---------========= grid schema contract is loaded =========---------'
      "

  schema-contract-builder:
    image: piashtanjin/schema-contract-builder:latest
    container_name: schema-contract-builder
    volumes:
      - pbft-shared:/pbft-shared
    entrypoint: |
      bash -c "
        while true; do curl -s http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008/state | grep -q head; if [ $$? -eq 0 ]; then break; fi; sleep 0.5; done;
        sabre cr --create grid_schema --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --owner $$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.pub) --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        sabre upload --filename /tmp/schema.yaml --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        sabre ns --create 621dee01 --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --owner $$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.pub) --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        sabre perm 621dee01 grid_schema --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --read --write --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        sabre perm 621dee05 grid_schema --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --read --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        echo '---------========= grid schema contract is loaded =========---------'
      "

  # pike-contract-builder:
  pike-contract-builder:
    image: piashtanjin/pike-contract-builder:latest
    container_name: pike-contract-builder
    volumes:
      - pbft-shared:/pbft-shared
    entrypoint: |
      bash -c "
        while true; do curl -s http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008/state | grep -q head; if [ $$? -eq 0 ]; then break; fi; sleep 0.5; done;
        sabre cr --create grid_pike --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --owner $$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.pub) --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        sabre upload --filename /tmp/pike.yaml --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        sabre ns --create 621dee05 --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --owner $$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.pub) --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        sabre perm 621dee05 grid_pike --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --read --write --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        echo '---------========= pike contract is loaded =========---------'
      "

  product-contract-builder:
    image: piashtanjin/product-contract-builder:latest
    container_name: product-contract-builder
    volumes:
      - pbft-shared:/pbft-shared
    entrypoint: |
      bash -c "
        while true; do curl -s http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008/state | grep -q head; if [ $$? -eq 0 ]; then break; fi; sleep 0.5; done;
        sabre cr --create grid_product --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --owner $$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.pub) --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        sabre upload --filename /tmp/product.yaml --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        sabre ns --create 621dee05 --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --owner $$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.pub) --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        sabre ns --create 621dee01 --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --owner $$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.pub) --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        sabre ns --create 621dee02 --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --owner $$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.pub) --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        sabre perm 621dee05 grid_product --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --read --write --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        sabre perm 621dee01 grid_product --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --read --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        sabre perm 621dee02 grid_product --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --read --write --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        echo '---------========= grid_product contract is loaded =========---------'
      "

  location-contract-builder:
    image: piashtanjin/location-contract-builder:latest
    container_name: location-contract-builder
    volumes:
      - pbft-shared:/pbft-shared
    entrypoint: |
      bash -c "
        while true; do curl -s http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008/state | grep -q head; if [ $$? -eq 0 ]; then break; fi; sleep 0.5; done;
        sabre cr --create grid_location --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --owner $$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.pub) --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        sabre upload --filename /tmp/location.yaml --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        sabre ns --create 621dee04 --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --owner $$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.pub) --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        sabre perm 621dee05 grid_location --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --read --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        sabre perm 621dee01 grid_location --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --read --write --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        sabre perm 621dee04 grid_location --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --read --write --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        echo '---------========= grid_location contract is loaded =========---------'
      "
  purchase-order-contract-builder:
    image: piashtanjin/purchase-order-contract-builder:latest
    container_name: purchase-order-contract-builder
    volumes:
      - pbft-shared:/pbft-shared
    entrypoint: |
      bash -c "
        while true; do curl -s http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008/state | grep -q head; if [ $$? -eq 0 ]; then break; fi; sleep 0.5; done;
        sabre cr --create grid_purchase_order --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --owner $$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.pub) --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        sabre upload --filename /tmp/purchase_order.yaml --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        sabre ns --create 621dee06 --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator --owner $$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.pub) --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        sabre perm 621dee05 grid_purchase_order --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --read --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        sabre perm 621dee06 grid_purchase_order --key /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0 --read --write --url http://sawtooth-rest-api-default-0:8008 --wait 30
        echo '---------========= grid_purchase_order contract is loaded =========---------'
      "
  # if [ ! -e sabre-admin.batch ]; then
  #     sawset proposal create \
  #         -k /root/.sawtooth/keys/my_key.priv \
  #         sawtooth.swa.administrators=$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.pub) \
  #         -o sabre-admin.batch
  #       sawadm genesis sabre-admin.batch
  validator-0:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-validator:nightly
    container_name: sawtooth-validator-default-0
    expose:
      - 4004
      - 5050
      - 8800
    ports:
      - "4004:4004"
    volumes:
      - pbft-shared:/pbft-shared
    command: |
      bash -c "
        if [ -e /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.priv ]; then
          cp /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.pub /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.pub
          cp /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.priv /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv
        fi &&
        if [ ! -e /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv ]; then
          sawadm keygen
          mkdir -p /pbft-shared/validators || true
          cp /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.pub /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.pub
          cp /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.priv
        fi &&
        if [ ! -e config-genesis.batch ]; then
          sawset genesis -k /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv -o config-genesis.batch
        fi &&
        while [[ ! -f /pbft-shared/validators/validator-1.pub || \
                 ! -f /pbft-shared/validators/validator-2.pub || \
                 ! -f /pbft-shared/validators/validator-3.pub || \
                 ! -f /pbft-shared/validators/validator-4.pub ]];
        do sleep 1; done
        echo sawtooth.consensus.pbft.members=\\['\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.pub)'\"','\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-1.pub)'\"','\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-2.pub)'\"','\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-3.pub)'\"','\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-4.pub)'\"'\\] &&
        if [ ! -e /root/.sawtooth/keys/my_key.priv ]; then
          sawtooth keygen my_key
        fi &&
        if [ ! -e config.batch ]; then
         sawset proposal create \
            -k /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv \
            sawtooth.consensus.algorithm.name=pbft \
            sawtooth.consensus.algorithm.version=1.0 \
            sawtooth.validator.transaction_families='[{"family": "sabre", "version": "0.5"}, {"family":"sawtoo", "version":"1.0"}, {"family":"xo", "version":"1.0"}]' \
            sawtooth.identity.allowed_keys=\\['\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.pub)'\"','\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-1.pub)'\"','\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-2.pub)'\"','\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-3.pub)'\"','\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-4.pub)'\"'\\] \
            sawtooth.swa.administrators=\\['\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.pub)'\"','\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-1.pub)'\"','\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-2.pub)'\"','\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-3.pub)'\"','\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-4.pub)'\"'\\] \
            sawtooth.consensus.pbft.members=\\['\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-0.pub)'\"','\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-1.pub)'\"','\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-2.pub)'\"','\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-3.pub)'\"','\"'$$(cat /pbft-shared/validators/validator-4.pub)'\"'\\] \
            sawtooth.publisher.max_batches_per_block=1200 \
            -o config.batch 
        fi &&
        if [ ! -e /var/lib/sawtooth/genesis.batch ]; then
          sawadm genesis config-genesis.batch config.batch 
        fi &&
        sawtooth-validator -vv \
          --endpoint tcp://validator-0:8800 \
          --bind component:tcp://eth0:4004 \
          --bind consensus:tcp://eth0:5050 \
          --bind network:tcp://eth0:8800 \
          --scheduler parallel \
          --peering static \
          --maximum-peer-connectivity 10000
      "
  validator-1:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-validator:nightly
    container_name: sawtooth-validator-default-1
    expose:
      - 4004
      - 5050
      - 8800
    volumes:
      - pbft-shared:/pbft-shared
    command: |
      bash -c "
        if [ -e /pbft-shared/validators/validator-1.priv ]; then
          cp /pbft-shared/validators/validator-1.pub /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.pub
          cp /pbft-shared/validators/validator-1.priv /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv
        fi &&
        if [ ! -e /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv ]; then
          sawadm keygen
          mkdir -p /pbft-shared/validators || true
          cp /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.pub /pbft-shared/validators/validator-1.pub
          cp /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv /pbft-shared/validators/validator-1.priv
        fi &&
        sawtooth keygen my_key &&
        sawtooth-validator -vv \
          --endpoint tcp://validator-1:8800 \
          --bind component:tcp://eth0:4004 \
          --bind consensus:tcp://eth0:5050 \
          --bind network:tcp://eth0:8800 \
          --scheduler parallel \
          --peering static \
          --maximum-peer-connectivity 10000 \
          --peers tcp://validator-0:8800
      "
  validator-2:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-validator:nightly
    container_name: sawtooth-validator-default-2
    expose:
      - 4004
      - 5050
      - 8800
    volumes:
      - pbft-shared:/pbft-shared
    command: |
      bash -c "
        if [ -e /pbft-shared/validators/validator-2.priv ]; then
          cp /pbft-shared/validators/validator-2.pub /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.pub
          cp /pbft-shared/validators/validator-2.priv /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv
        fi &&
        if [ ! -e /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv ]; then
          sawadm keygen
          mkdir -p /pbft-shared/validators || true
          cp /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.pub /pbft-shared/validators/validator-2.pub
          cp /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv /pbft-shared/validators/validator-2.priv
        fi &&
        sawtooth keygen my_key &&
        sawtooth-validator -vv \
          --endpoint tcp://validator-2:8800 \
          --bind component:tcp://eth0:4004 \
          --bind consensus:tcp://eth0:5050 \
          --bind network:tcp://eth0:8800 \
          --scheduler parallel \
          --peering static \
          --maximum-peer-connectivity 10000 \
          --peers tcp://validator-0:8800 \
          --peers tcp://validator-1:8800
      "
  validator-3:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-validator:nightly
    container_name: sawtooth-validator-default-3
    expose:
      - 4004
      - 5050
      - 8800
    volumes:
      - pbft-shared:/pbft-shared
    command: |
      bash -c "
        if [ -e /pbft-shared/validators/validator-3.priv ]; then
         cp /pbft-shared/validators/validator-3.pub /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.pub
         cp /pbft-shared/validators/validator-3.priv /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv
        fi &&
        if [ ! -e /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv ]; then
         sawadm keygen
         mkdir -p /pbft-shared/validators || true
         cp /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.pub /pbft-shared/validators/validator-3.pub
         cp /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv /pbft-shared/validators/validator-3.priv
        fi &&
        sawtooth keygen my_key &&
        sawtooth-validator -vv \
          --endpoint tcp://validator-3:8800 \
          --bind component:tcp://eth0:4004 \
          --bind consensus:tcp://eth0:5050 \
          --bind network:tcp://eth0:8800 \
          --scheduler parallel \
          --peering static \
          --maximum-peer-connectivity 10000 \
          --peers tcp://validator-0:8800 \
          --peers tcp://validator-1:8800 \
          --peers tcp://validator-2:8800
      "
  validator-4:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-validator:nightly
    container_name: sawtooth-validator-default-4
    expose:
      - 4004
      - 5050
      - 8800
    volumes:
      - pbft-shared:/pbft-shared
    command: |
      bash -c "
        if [ -e /pbft-shared/validators/validator-4.priv ]; then
          cp /pbft-shared/validators/validator-4.pub /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.pub
          cp /pbft-shared/validators/validator-4.priv /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv
        fi &&
        if [ ! -e /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv ]; then
          sawadm keygen
          mkdir -p /pbft-shared/validators || true
          cp /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.pub /pbft-shared/validators/validator-4.pub
          cp /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv /pbft-shared/validators/validator-4.priv
        fi &&
        sawtooth keygen my_key &&
        sawtooth-validator -vv \
          --endpoint tcp://validator-4:8800 \
          --bind component:tcp://eth0:4004 \
          --bind consensus:tcp://eth0:5050 \
          --bind network:tcp://eth0:8800 \
          --scheduler parallel \
          --peering static \
          --maximum-peer-connectivity 10000 \
          --peers tcp://validator-0:8800 \
          --peers tcp://validator-1:8800 \
          --peers tcp://validator-2:8800 \
          --peers tcp://validator-3:8800
      "
  sawtooth-rest-api:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-rest-api:latest
    container_name: sawtooth-rest-api-default-0
    expose:
      - 8008
    ports:
      - "8008:8008"
    depends_on:
      - validator-0
    command: |
      bash -c "
        sawtooth-rest-api \
          --connect tcp://validator-0:4004 \
          --bind sawtooth-rest-api:8008
      "
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  sawtooth-rest-api1:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-rest-api:nightly
    container_name: sawtooth-rest-api-1
    expose:
      - 8008
    depends_on:
      - validator-0
    command: |
      bash -c "
        sawtooth-rest-api -v --connect tcp://validator-1:4004 --bind sawtooth-rest-api1:8008
      "
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  sawtooth-rest-api2:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-rest-api:nightly
    container_name: sawtooth-rest-api-2
    expose:
      - 8008
    depends_on:
      - validator-0
    command: |
      bash -c "
        sawtooth-rest-api -v --connect tcp://validator-2:4004 --bind sawtooth-rest-api2:8008
      "
    stop_signal: SIGKILL
  sawtooth-rest-api3:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-rest-api:nightly
    container_name: sawtooth-rest-api-3
    expose:
      - 8008
    depends_on:
      - validator-0
    command: |
      bash -c "
        sawtooth-rest-api -v --connect tcp://validator-3:4004 --bind sawtooth-rest-api3:8008
      "
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  sawtooth-rest-api4:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-rest-api:nightly
    container_name: sawtooth-rest-api-4
    expose:
      - 8008
    depends_on:
      - validator-0
    command: |
      bash -c "
        sawtooth-rest-api -v --connect tcp://validator-4:4004 --bind sawtooth-rest-api4:8008
      "
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  sawtooth-settings-tp:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-settings-tp:latest
    container_name: sawtooth-settings-tp
    expose:
      - 4004
    command: settings-tp -v -C tcp://validator-0:4004
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  sawtooth-settings-tp-1:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-settings-tp:latest
    container_name: sawtooth-settings-tp-1
    expose:
      - 4004
    command: settings-tp -v -C tcp://validator-1:4004
    stop_signal: SIGKILL
  
  sawtooth-settings-tp-2:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-settings-tp:latest
    container_name: sawtooth-settings-tp-2
    expose:
      - 4004
    command: settings-tp -v -C tcp://validator-2:4004
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  sawtooth-settings-tp-3:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-settings-tp:latest
    container_name: sawtooth-settings-tp-3
    expose:
      - 4004
    command: settings-tp -v -C tcp://validator-3:4004
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  sawtooth-settings-tp-4:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-settings-tp:latest
    container_name: sawtooth-settings-tp-4
    expose:
      - 4004
    command: settings-tp -v -C tcp://validator-4:4004
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  sabre-tp:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-sabre-tp:0.8
    container_name: sawtooth-sabre-tp
    depends_on:
      - validator-0
    entrypoint: sawtooth-sabre -vv --connect tcp://validator-0:4004

  sawtooth-client:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-shell:nightly
    container_name: sawtooth-shell
    volumes:
      - pbft-shared:/pbft-shared
    depends_on:
      - validator-0
    command: |
      bash -c "
        sawtooth keygen &&
        tail -f /dev/null
      "
    stop_signal: SIGKILL
  pbft-0:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-pbft-engine:nightly
    container_name: sawtooth-pbft-engine-default-0
    command: pbft-engine -vv --connect tcp://validator-0:5050
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  pbft-1:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-pbft-engine:nightly
    container_name: sawtooth-pbft-engine-default-1
    command: pbft-engine -vv --connect tcp://validator-1:5050
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  pbft-2:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-pbft-engine:nightly
    container_name: sawtooth-pbft-engine-default-2
    command: pbft-engine -vv --connect tcp://validator-2:5050
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  pbft-3:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-pbft-engine:nightly
    container_name: sawtooth-pbft-engine-default-3
    command: pbft-engine -vv --connect tcp://validator-3:5050
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  pbft-4:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-pbft-engine:nightly
    container_name: sawtooth-pbft-engine-default-4
    command: pbft-engine -vv --connect tcp://validator-4:5050
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  # ---== alpha node ==---

  db-alpha:
    image: postgres
    container_name: db-alpha
    hostname: db-alpha
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: grid
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: grid_example
      POSTGRES_DB: grid

  gridd-alpha:
    image: gridd
    container_name: gridd-alpha
    hostname: gridd-alpha
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: daemon/Dockerfile
      args:
        - REPO_VERSION=${REPO_VERSION}
        - CARGO_ARGS= --features experimental
    volumes:
      - contracts-shared:/usr/share/scar
      - pbft-shared:/pbft-shared
      - gridd-alpha:/etc/grid/keys
      - cache-shared:/var/cache/grid
    expose:
      - 8080
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      GRID_DAEMON_KEY: "alpha-agent"
      GRID_DAEMON_ENDPOINT: "http://gridd-alpha:8080"
    entrypoint: |
      bash -c "
        # we need to wait for the db to have started.
        until PGPASSWORD=grid_example psql -h db-alpha -U grid -c '\q' > /dev/null 2>&1; do
            >&2 echo \"Database is unavailable - sleeping\"
            sleep 1
        done
        grid keygen --skip && \
        grid keygen --system --skip && \
        grid -vv database migrate \
            -C postgres://grid:grid_example@db-alpha/grid &&
        gridd -vv -b 0.0.0.0:8080 -k root -C tcp://validator-0:4004 \
            --database-url postgres://grid:grid_example@db-alpha/grid
      "
```